# How do you install GUI on POWERPC Ubuntu 14.10 Server?

Tags: server, gui, powerpc

I have a PowerPC iMac G4, and would like to have Utopic Unicorn Desktop on it alongside Mac OS X. Unfortunately, I have only found a Server ISO. Can I just do

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

Or is it more complicated/impossible?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, this will install the Unity desktop, as you would have it in a normal desktop disk image

Comment: ISO for Utopic could be found here: http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.10/